# Express.js Automatically append key:value to res.send()

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express.js app and I would like to add a key for whether the user is logged in. For example:

```
export const indexRouter = express.Router();

indexRouter.get('/', (_, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.send({ message: 'HI' });
});
```

and I want the output to look like `{ message: "HI", loggedin: true }`

Answer (score 0):

Even when you use an `after middleware`, it cannot modify the response that had been sent. The only way is to use an utility function. E.g:

```
indexRouter.get('/', (_, res) => {
    response(res, { message: 'HI' });
});

function response(res, data) {
  data.loggedin = true;
  res.send(data)
}
```